# Efficiently computing a pair(base, exponent) representation of an integer n

Tags: java, decomposition

I'm having trouble with desiging a method to express an integer n as an integer pair (base, exponent) such that `n == base ^ exponent`, for an assignment. Below  is the contract for the method. @pre specifies what *n* has to be, @post defines what the output has to be.

```
/**
* Writes a number as a power with maximal exponent.
*
* @param n  the number to 'powerize'
* @return  power decomposition of {@code n} with maximal exponent
* @throws IllegalArgumentException  if precondition violated
* @pre {@code 2 <= n}
* @post {@code n == power(\result) &&
*     (\forall int b, int e;
*      2 <= b && 1 <= e && n == b ^ e;
*      e <= \result.exponent)}
*/
public static Power powerize(int n){}
```

Where the class Power is just a Pair instance.

I already managed to solve this problem using a naive approach, in which I compute the value of the base and exponent by computing `log(n) / log(b)` with `2 <= b <= sqrt(n)`. But the assignment description says I have to produce an ellegant & efficient method and I couldn't find a way to compute this more efficiently.

Comment: you can define a class with two properties `base` and `exponent` and implement getter and setter for them to be accessed using objects of the same class

Comment: Iterate `e` in `log(n) / log(2) >= e >= 1` and calculate `b = exp(log(n) / e)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consulting some books I designed the following solution:

Input int *n*: 
Let *p<sub>1</sub>...p<sub>m</sub>* be m unique primes. 
Then we can express *n* as:

  *n = p<sub>1</sub><sup>e<sub>1</sub></sup> x ... x p<sub>m</sub><sup>e<sub>m</sub></sup>.*

Then compute the gcd *d* of e<sub>1</sub> ... e<sub>m</sub> using the euclidean algorithm. 
Then we express n as:

  *n = (p<sub>1</sub><sup>e<sub>1</sub>/d</sup> x ... x p<sub>m</sub><sup>e<sub>m</sub>/d</sup>)<sup>d</sup>.*

now we have:

  *b = p<sub>1</sub><sup>e<sub>1</sub>/d</sup> x ... x p<sub>m</sub><sup>e<sub>m</sub>/d</sup>*

  e = d

return new Power(b, e)